# Large List Data Source

Tags: sharepoint-online

Large list data source -

1. I have seven large Excel spreadsheets (between 4,000 and 12,000 line items) that I'd like to use as a data source in Power Apps.

2. Each list represents a 'Region'. I get the lists emailed to me quarterly from another program.

3. The Power App would need to filter the data source by column 'Region', column, 'City' or column 'Location ID'.
4. What is the most efficient way to manage such data (Excel or SP List), recognizing that the same reports are provided every 90 days - and the data may or may not have been deleted, edited, or be new in the set.
5. Should the lists remain separated or combined? If SP is the preferred method how should the data be most efficiently and accurately imported into SP?

Answer (score 0):

If you have large data, it's more suggested to separate the data into different lists.

We could create a new list start from Excel as shown below:

[image]

Yes we could also use filtering to modify a SharePoint view so that the list will be more efficient.

More information:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-list-0d397414-d95f-41eb-addd-5e6eff41b083?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us